# Как изменить цвет текста в Lua?

Tags: lua

Например:

```
print("TEXT")
```

Что бы этот текст был красным (red)?
И шрифт,размер?

Answer (score 7):

Используя [ansicolors](https://github.com/hoelzro/ansicolors):

```
local colors = require 'ansicolors'
print(colors.red 'hello') // применение
```

Comment: Это не работает,выдает ошибку " Running lua script: test.lua cstrike/lua/test.lua:2: attempt to index global 'color' (a nil value)" почему ?

Comment: @user10131, потому что в примере `colors`, с буквой ***s*** на конце, а у вас, судя по сообщению об ошибке - `color`.